# How to use malloc with madvise and enable MADV_DONTDUMP option

Tags: c, linux, unix, malloc, posix

I'm looking to use `madvise` and `malloc` but I have always the same error:

> madvise error: Invalid argument

I tried to use the `MADV_DONTDUMP` to save some space in my binaries but it didn't work.

The page size is 4096.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *p_optimize_object;
    unsigned int optimize_object_size = 4096*256;

    optimize_object_size = ((optimize_object_size / 4096) + 1) * 4096;
    printf("optimize_object_size = %d\n", optimize_object_size);
    p_optimize_object = malloc(optimize_object_size);
    if (madvise(p_optimize_object, optimize_object_size, MADV_DONTDUMP | MADV_SEQUENTIAL) == -1)
    {
        perror("madvise error");
    }
    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the command:

```
$ gcc -g -O3 madvice.c  && ./a.out
```

Output:

> madvise error: Invalid argument

Comment: Do you realise that `sizeof(optimize_object_size)` is most probably equal to 4 ?

Comment: Please don't correct your question if answers are already given; this would invalidate the (otherwise correct) answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `sizeof` is wrong; you are allocating only four bytes of memory (sizeof unsigned int), and calling madvise() with a size argument of 1M for the same chunk of memory.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *p_optimize_object;
    unsigned int optimize_object_size = 4096*256;

    optimize_object_size = ((optimize_object_size / 4096) + 1) * 4096;
    printf("optimize_object_size = %d\n", optimize_object_size);
    p_optimize_object = malloc(sizeof(optimize_object_size));
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocated %zu bytes\n",  sizeof(optimize_object_size));

    if (madvise(p_optimize_object, optimize_object_size, MADV_WILLNEED | MADV_SEQUENTIAL) == -1)
    {
        perror("madvise error");
    }
    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

---

```
optimize_object_size = 1052672
Allocated 4 bytes
madvise error: Invalid argument
OK
```

---

UPDATE:

And the other problem is that malloc() can give you non-aligned memory (probably with an alignment of 4,8,16,...), where madvice() wants page-aligned memory:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *p_optimize_object;
    unsigned int optimize_object_size = 4096*256;
    int rc;

    optimize_object_size = ((optimize_object_size / 4096) + 1) * 4096;
    printf("optimize_object_size = %d\n", optimize_object_size);
#if 0
    p_optimize_object = malloc(sizeof(optimize_object_size));
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocated %zu bytes\n",  sizeof(optimize_object_size));

#elif 0
    p_optimize_object = malloc(optimize_object_size);
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocated %zu bytes\n",  optimize_object_size);
#else
    rc = posix_memalign (&p_optimize_object, 4096, optimize_object_size);
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocated %zu bytes:%d\n",  optimize_object_size, rc);
#endif
    // if (madvise(p_optimize_object, optimize_object_size, MADV_WILLNEED | MADV_SEQUENTIAL) == -1)
    if (madvise(p_optimize_object, optimize_object_size, MADV_WILLNEED | MADV_DONTFORK) == -1)
    {
        perror("madvise error");
    }
    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

---

```
$ ./a.out
optimize_object_size = 1052672
Allocated 1052672 bytes:0
OK
```

---

And the alignement requerement appears to be linux-specific:

> Linux Notes
>          The current Linux implementation (2.4.0) views this system call more as a command than as advice and hence may return an error when  it  cannot
>          do what it usually would do in response to this advice.  (See the ERRORS description above.)  This is non-standard behavior.
>
> The  Linux  implementation requires that the address addr be page-aligned, and allows length to be zero.  If there are some parts of the speci‐
>          fied address range that are not mapped, the Linux version of madvise() ignores them and applies the call to the rest (but returns  ENOMEM  from
>          the system call, as it should).

---

Finally:

> I tried to use the MADV_DONTDUMP to save some space in my binaries but it didn't work.

Which, of course, doesn't make sense. Malloc or posix_memalign add to your address space, making (at least) the VSIZ of your running program larger. What happens to the this space is completely in the hands of the (kernel) memory manager, driven by your program's references to the particular memory, with *maybe* a few hints from madvice.

Comment: You may not use `madvise`on memory from either `malloc` or `posix_memalign`. It might appear to work, but it is incorrect and will break things sooner or later. Most likely it will break malloc internals and/or future allocations when the memory is freed and later reused by malloc.

Comment: Where did you read that? The linux man page only mentions address space: `in the address range beginning at address addr and with size length bytes.` Which doen'st surprise me, since (low level) memory management is performed on pages -->> page table entries. For managing entries in tables it doesn't matter what they refer to. (as long as they don't belong to DMA, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can't and even if you could do it in certain cases with certain flags (and the flags you're trying to use here should be relatively harmless), you shouldn't. `madvise` operates on memory from lower level allocations than `malloc` gives you and messing with the memory from malloc will likely break malloc.

If you want some block of memory that you can call `madvise` on, you should obtain it using `mmap`.

Answer (score -1):

> I tried to use the `MADV_DONTDUMP` to *save some space in my binaries* but it didn't work.

Read again, and more carefully, the [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) `man` page.

The address should be page aligned. The result of `malloc` is generally not page aligned (page size is often 4Kbytes, but see [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) for `SC_PAGESIZE`). Use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) to ask for a page-aligned segment in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

**You won't save any space** in your binary [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). You'll just save space in your *core* dump, see [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html). And *core dumps should not happen*. See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (read also about [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) and [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

To disable core dumps, consider rather [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CORE` (or the `ulimit -c` [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) in your terminal running a `bash` shell).

Comment: Sometime, it is needed to protect memory area not to be dumped in core. It is to secure your sensitive information present process memory to be dumped in core. Consider, your process is having "private RSA key" or "signature key" loaded for encrypt or sign operation. In this context, if process crash due to some reason (bug or explicit coredump command), this memory will be dumped and senstive private key or signature key is revealed, which you have not intended.

Comment: On Linux, core dumps can be configured very precisely. And `madvise` has `MADV_DONTDUMP`; of course, any good program can disable `core`  dumps entirely. If it dump core, it is the programmer's fault, not the computer's fault or the user's fault.