# Dont dump variables in gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

Im trying to find if there is a way to hide/avoid printing variable values in case of core dump. I see when there is a core dump, when traversed through gdb, we are able to find the value of the variables which is expected, but in need of a way where this doesnt happen. I came across this particular link in my quest for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662565/how-to-use-malloc-with-madvise-and-enable-madv-dontdump-option/46664586). But I still see the values being printed.

(gdb) p data
$1 = (void *) 0x615000
(gdb)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have some secrets in your code you don't want to be visible in GDB?

Comment: Well yes, say a secret code being saved in a variable and I wouldnt want that to be let out when gdb

Comment: _Even if_ you are trying to protect a genuine secret (like an encryption key), messing with what goes into core dumps is only going to make your own life harder.  It won't help at all against a determined adversary.  You need to be looking at things like [privilege separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation) and [address space isolation](https://lwn.net/Articles/835342/), to make it so the secret is never in a ptrace-able process's memory in the first place.

Comment: You can't hide anything that is in memory or in a register from GDB (or other debugger or simple memory dump). If you have secrets, depending on how critical they are, you will have to obfuscate or encrypt them. But without proper root of trust it will not hide them completely.

Comment: If you're running Intel Skylake or later, you can use [SGX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Guard_Extensions) to keep data private.

Answer (score 2):

> Im trying to find if there is a way to hide/avoid printing variable values in case of core dump.

The usual way to achieve that is install a signal handler for all fatal signals.

In the handler, you would zero out all secret variables, then reset the handler to `SIG_DFL` and re-`raise` the signal.

> say a secret code being saved in a variable and I wouldnt want that to be let out when gdb

Certainly `madvise(...MADV_DONTDUMP)` in your linked answer will not achieve that.

You can use some anti-debugging techniques, such as `fork()` followed by `ptrace` attach, with the child and parent using a complicated handshake and the child only decoding secrets when it knows that it's being traced by a trusted parent.

Beware: you will have very hard time debugging your program when it goes wrong, and a sufficiently motivated attacker in control of the machine will defeat your protections anyway.

Your efforts are likely better spent elsewhere.